# How to post video to facebook page with custom thumbnail using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I can upload video to facebook page using the graphic api. But I am not able to upload it with a custom video thumbnail. I tried to add "picture" parameter but facebook just ignore this parameter. I can able to change the video thumbnail on facebook page by clicking the "edit" of the video post. So, I think there is some way to do it from the API as well but I just can't find it.

Here is the code I used to upload the video to facebook page:

```
$data = [
  'title'        => 'MY POST TITLE',
  'description'  => 'MY POST DESCRIPTION',
  'source'       => new CURLFile('video/my_video.mp4', 'video/mp4'),
  'access_token' => FACEBOOK_PAGE_TOKEN,
];

// Curl Post Url
$post_url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/'.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID.'/videos';

// CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I think there is some way to do it from the API as well but I just can't find it.

Check the list of parameters listed in the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos#Creating

> `thumb` [image]: The video thumbnail raw data to be uploaded and associated with a video.

Comment: how can I add the image file? add 'thumb'=> 'http://xxxxx.com/xxx.jpg' to the data aray?

Comment: It shows an error to me "Invalid format. It should be an image file data." How can I add image type as parameter?

Comment: It explicitly says, “video thumbnail __raw data__” – you need to upload it as a file, same as you’re doing with the video itself.

Comment: i tried the same way as the video, but i got the same error message

Comment: Hi @CBroe please could you elaborate what this means "“video thumbnail raw data” I cannot make sense of how to send raw image data. The API docs dont explain this properly at all. Facebook is currently choosing the worst possible thumbnail for al the videos I post and always the same.

Comment: @MitchellK standard, run-of-the-mill HTTP image upload, as part of the `multipart/form-data` request.

Comment: Thanks so much @CBroe I just figured it out. With curl, which is what I am using the file must be sent as follows `  -F "thumb=@/mydirectory/videothumb.jpg" ` I was just missing the `@` thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook PHP SDK this process is a little bit simpler:

```
<?php

use Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile;

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$data = [
   'thumb'        => new FacebookFile('PATH TO YOUR THUMB FILE'),
    'source'      => $fb->videoToUpload('PATH TO YOUR VIDEO FILE'),
    'title'       => 'YOUR VIDEO TITLE',
    'description' => 'YOUR VIDEO DESCRIPTION!'
];

$response = $fb->post('/YOUR_PAGE_ID/videos', $data, YOUR_PAGE_TOKEN);
$post = $response->getGraphObject();
var_dump( $post );
```

Just remember to load facebook/graph-sdk as your project dependency in composer.json.